# How to change div with same class after some time?

Tags: jquery

What i want is to change this `advertise_container` every 30 second and display another from foreach. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
 <div id="advertise_holder">

      @foreach($advertises as $advertise)
        <div class="row advertise_container">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="advertisement">
                 <img src="{{ home_asset('img/advertisment1.png') }}" alt=""  />
                  <div class="advertisment_text">
                    <div class="advertisement_title">Your ad can be here</div>
                    <div class="advertisment_subtitle">ADVERTISE WITH SKYMO</div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
           @endforeach
           </div>
```

In script i know that i need to use `each` function:

```
 $( ".advertise_container" ).each(function( index ) {

  });
```

Right now it display 3 divs. What i want is to make something like slider. To show first div, and after some time second and so on...

Comment: Please be more specific about you Problems

Comment: I updated my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
Create function to show next advrt.:

```
function showNext(){
 var next=$('.advertise_container.active').next('.advertise_container');
 if(!next.length)  {
   next=$('.advertise_container').first();
 } 
 $('.advertise_container.active').fadeOut('slow',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('active');
    next.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active');
  });
}
```

Show 1st on document ready and then other after 2 seconds:

```
$(function(){

 //add active class to first el
  $('.advertise_container.active').first().addClass('active');


 //show first time
  showNext(); 

  //show next after 2 seconds (you can change time)
  setInterval(showNext,2000); 
});
```

add this CSS class as well:

```
.advertise_container {
   display:none;
 }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sz3g109y/5/)

Comment: Problem is that i foreach that and i cannot add active class only on first then it all divs would have that class

Answer (score 0):

Test this,

But if you have single div to replace, use

```
    if ($( ".advertise_container" ).next().length > 0){
          $( ".advertise_container").
removeClass("advertise_container").
next().addClass('advertise_container');
    }
```

will be more efficient.

V.

Comment: maybe u didn't understand me. I display few divs , and i want to show only first and after some time i want to display second div... and so on...